# Activitymanager leaking the activity

Tags: android

When we are initializing the ActivityManager for first Time in android code. Is it caching the context of calling activity?

> ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem ? Do you have issue log and more detailed source ?

Comment: @Johann67 ...I am working on messaging app. where before using the app u should configured the AccountSetup Details, This all happens inside the MainActivity which calling the child activity by passing the context. Inside the child activty , we r initializing the ActivityManager and checking  is it in lock task mode or not

Comment: the "this" in your code refers to activity context. If you will be using AM after killing this activity i guess it will result in context leak. Also, for starting another activity why do you need to pass context?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my Samsung Note 5 mobile phone and found that the problem can be solved by using the application context as follows.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

It seems the reason is caused by the activity context is kept by a static reference on some Samsung devices,  more info can refer to [this thread](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/177).